# largeTitleDisplayMode doesn't work when using UIHostingController

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using a UIHostingController to host my SwiftUI content, I can't get the navigation title to start large and shift to inline as the user scrolls. Is this a known problem with using the UIHostingController?

```swift
    var viewModel: DashboardViewModel!
    lazy var contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: DashboardView(viewModel: viewModel))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addChild(contentView)
        view.addSubview(contentView.view)
        setupConstraints()
        navigationItem.title = "Test Title"
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
```

The title shows in-line, even if I set the mode to .always.

After researching some more, I find the problem is my SwiftUI:

```swift
 var body: some View {
   ZStack {
      Color.<customColor>.ignoresSafeArea()
      ScrollView {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Doing the ZStack causes issues with the NavBar

**Before Scrolling**

[image: Before Scroll]

**After Scrolling — See how the Card is up behind the title**

[image: After Scroll]